# Java writing CSV files to be loaded into SQL Server, format incorrect

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, csv

Attempting to develop a script which will output a CSV file. Initially I was using CSVWriter, but switched to BufferedWriter in an attempting to debug the problem.

I have attempting many iterations of this CSV output, however they all seem to break on a row which has a very large amount of text >16000 characters in some cases. Everything looks fine when I attempt to open in notepad++, but when I attempt to load into SQL server to bring into excel it breaks my last column.

```
String[] row = null;
//change all " to "" in order to escape properly
tmp = tmp.replace("\"","\"\"");
bw.write(row[0]+","+row[1]+","+row[2]+","+row[3]+","+row[4]+","+row[16]+","+"\""+tmp+"\""+ ";" );
```

Above is what I am performing at the moment. However I attempted using the CSVWriter which would wrap every field in a "", this did not load.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: you do not escape linefeeds, may that be a problem?

Comment: post the error you are getting as well

Comment: The last separator is a ";" while all the others are ","

Comment: IF you are takling about tmp = tmp.replace("\"","\"\"");. If the quotes are not escaped than the row value will end when it hits the single quote within that string. For example "this is a test"<--was not the end " thishfiosj " . I would need to change ""<--was not the end ""

Comment: thst, the commas are the column delimiter while the semicolon is the row

Comment: Hussain Akhtar Wahid, when I attempt to load into the table I can preview the data. The last column which is contained within the "tmp" variable in the above code is broken into separate pieces.